# winforms Web Browser control Javascript issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

We have winforms application that has web browser control. We invoke webpages that gets rendered fine. If we are invoking javascript from C# code behind of the website, we get in to script errors.
For eg: 
Reponse.wirte("alert('hi');");

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which kind of error do you get?

Comment: after that none of the scripts work. like jquery undefined, $ undefined etc..and even page alignment gets disturbed

Comment: It is called `Response.Write`, not `Response.wirte` (Casing wrong and spelling wrong). Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: That is a typ from my side.. else C# would havegiven compile time error

Comment: @Saravanan in which part of page do you write your script? Can you provide full code example?

Comment: I write in Page load event, for example i validate from and to date if they are not proper, we do Response.Write("<script>alert('Enter proper date!');</script>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The script has to be registered with the page using "RegisterStartupScript" and call existing code.
Defined one javascript function called "AlertMessage(msg)" and pass the required value from C# code behind thro' `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DisplayFunction", "AlertMessage('msg');", true);`